# Can you Edit .jar/archive contents inline with emacs

Tags: emacs

I know you can navigate the contents of an archive with emacs. Is there a way you can edit those files in place and write the archive transparently?. Currently, I navigate into the archive, write the file to a temp directory, and the use the java jar command to add the file back into the archive. Its a little bit of pain.

P.S. I know there are few use cases where you'd want to do this, but I've inherited a platform that I can't readily modify where I have to cope with this limitation in the short term.

Comment: If you have zip command installed on your machine, Emacs can write to jar files with no efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it just works.  Did you try it?

I grabbed a jar file that contained a text file and some java code that would print it out.  I edited the txt file within the .jar and saved the text file.  It did exactly what I would expect.

EDIT- When saving the archive make sure you use C-x C-s

Comment: @nsfyn55 Note that the procedure in this case is to open the enclosing jar file in Emacs, then navigate to individual files using the dired-like interface.

Comment: @sanity/Dustin I am using the default emacs 2.3 version that ships with ubuntu 10.04 with no window mode. When I open the jar /mydir/myjar.jar, edit the file(/mydir/myjar.jar:props.properties), and use c-x c-w to write It asks if I want to write to /mydir/. If I try to append the jar file name on there it wants to overwrite the jar

Comment: I'm sure you mean 23, not 2.3.  Do you have a permissions problem or something?  I just tried with 23.2.1 on my ubuntu (11.04) box with no issues.  Also on my mac with whatever version they shipped.

Comment: Oh wait, you're hitting C-x C-w -- that's what that *means*.  Just use C-x C-s

Answer (score 1):

In emacs-23.2 (not 23.1 or 23.3) this doesn't "just work" on Windows due to a bug. Instead it just writes `caution: filename not matched: "<internal path>`.

One solution is to simply upgrade to 23.3.

To fix the bug in emacs-23.2, open `$EMACS_HOME/lisp/arc-mode.el` and replace:

```
(if (equal (car archive-zip-extract) "unzip")
     (shell-quote-argument name)
       name)
```

with:

```
name
```

and recompile:

```
M-x byte-compile-file $EMACS_HOME/lisp/arc-mode.el
```

This answer comes from the original [emacs bug report](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=6144).